# avoid clipping in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

Here's a question that seems like a common issue and yet looking online I couldn't find a decent solution for my task

Clipping with objects - not walls.

In my scene of a VR supermarket I have many items with rigidbody and boxcollider, and my problem is that there's a cart, that is a child of the FPController, and it is clipping with the items (see pic).

The FPController, is now changed to [CameraRig], since its a VR project. The cart is a child object of the [CameraRig] prefab. I move using teleport, so the cart teleports with the user. I want the cart to be restricted to the NavMesh borders, just like the NavMesh Agents. This way, for sure the cart will not collide with my "static" objects.

Can this be done with Unity?

The picture is in a scene mode.

I've been looking to some solutions like in here: youtube.com/watch?v=At_Zac4Xezw&t=1422s (22:00)

but it's not the user that is clipping but the cart. Any suggestions?

[Cart with collider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SmPz.jpg)
[Cart colliding with items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsEtY.jpg)

Comment: Well, colliders do a good job of preventing objects from clipping into each other...do you have one on your cart?

Comment: And is it big enough? Have you tried making it bigger?

Comment: Hello Serlite and Draco 18s, my cart has 6 collides (this is to prevent items from falling out), these are box colliders but they're not set as "triggers". They surround the whole cart (I'll add a photo in my edit)